NEON optimisation techniques for cortex-A35
Is there any tricks to efficiently utilise the NEON feature in Cortex-A35. I believe the Cortex-A35 has in-order execution, so what is the correct ways to load and process data.

I need to load data into batch of neon buffers to hide data latency (ie. found in case of cortex-A8 article)?
Combining LOAD-STORE operations improve CPU cycles (Does this execute parallely)?
Does pre-load improves data-cache in case of consecutive buffer access?
Does ARM code and NEON execute parallely, so can i combine ARM and NEON to improve CPU cycle?


For A35, this old post has a good diagram and description of the pipeline which will be helpful.
On your specific points:

I need to load data into batch of neon buffers to hide data latency (ie. found in case of cortex-A8 article)?

The Cortex-A8 CPU is a wider cpu (i.e. has more pipelines) so you're unlikely to benefit the same way. See: Is ARM Cortex-A8 pipeline 13 stage or 14 stage?
You'll likely get more benefit by properly scheduling instructions rather than batching them.

Combining LOAD-STORE operations improve CPU cycles (Does this execute parallelly)?

The Cortex-A35 (per the diagram) has only 1 load/store unit, so no.

Does pre-load improve data-cache in case of consecutive buffer access?

Only if the data fits into L1, otherwise you'll end up evicting the cache of the earlier loads with the later ones

Does ARM code and NEON execute parallelly, so can I combine ARM and NEON to improve CPU cycle?

Yes,  if you look at the diagram the Integer and NEON pipes are different. So they can execute in parallel. Do note however that some NEON instructions still also use the Integer pipeline as well.

